# Does anyone use backlogs with redmine 2.4.2 successfully?

Tags: redmine

I am about to install redmine with backlogs plugin in a new server, and find the newest version of redmine is 2.4.2. Any people makes them work together successfully?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical question about what others feel like you should do in an extremely narrow timeframe. Ask the backlogs guys what they support or just try it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has tried this.See below

https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/issues/1020